# Cannot reduce time taken to add constraints to pulp

Tags: python, optimization, python-multiprocessing, pulp

I have the following code(python 3) for adding constraints to pulp(v 2.3). It needs to add up to 400000 constraints(100^2 S, 4 A).

```
    def linearProgram(self, error = 1e-12):
        lp_problem = p.LpProblem('best-Vpi', p.LpMinimize)

        #create problem variables
        V = p.LpVariable.dicts("V",range(self.S), cat = "Continuous")
        #objective function
        for i in range(self.S):
            self.v.append(V[i])
        lp_problem += p.lpSum(self.v)
        #constraints
        for s in range(self.S):
            for a in range(self.A):
                pv = p.LpAffineExpression([(V[x],self.T[s][a][x]) for x in range(self.S)])
                constraint = p.lpSum([self.PR[s][a], self.gamma*pv ])
                lp_problem += V[s] >= constraint

        status = lp_problem.solve(p.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg = 0)) #solve
```

I can't seem to be able to optimise it further..

I even tried multiprocessing, but it gave a lot of errors-

```
    def __addconstraints(self, S0, S1, lp_problem):
        for s in range(S0, S1):
            for a in range(self.A):
                pv= p.lpDot(self.T[s][a],self.v)
                lp_problem += self.v[s] >= p.lpSum([self.PR[s][a], self.gamma*pv])
   ..................
   #in linearProgram
        if self.S%4:
            s0, s1 = 0, self.S//3
        else:
            s0, s1 = 0, self.S//4
        incr = s1
        processes = []
        for x in range(4):
            proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.__addconstraints, args=(s0, s1, lp_problem))
            processes.append(proc)
            proc.start()
            s0 = s1
            s1 = min(s1+incr, self.S)

        for proc in processes:
            proc.join()

        hard code for episodic? no need (due to initialization of mdp)
        if self.mdptype=="episodic":
            for state in self.end:
                lp_problem += V[state] == 0
```

I am new to both pulp and multiprocessing, so I don't really have an idea what I'm doing :p

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you first build a `p.LpAffineExpression`, then you apply a `p.lpSum` and finally you do a third operation on the result `V[s] >= constraint`. The two last operations may increase the time because the expression is being copied each time.

From my experience, the fastest times I've gotten are doing the following:

```py
# _vars_tup is a list of (key, value) pairs where each key is a variable and each value is a coefficient.
#  it's like initializing a dictionary.
# CONSTANT is a python number (not a pulp variable)
model += p.LpAffineExpression(_vars_tup, constant=CONSTANT) >= 0
```

The idea is to reduce the number of times you do operations with `p.LpAffineExpression` objects, because a copy is done at each operation. So, build the list of variables and coefficients (`_vars_tup`) for ALL the variables present in the constraint and then at the last step create the `p.LpAffineExpression` and compare it with a constant.

An equivalent way would be (although I haven't tried it):

```py
const = p.LpConstraint(e=p.LpAffineExpression(_vars_tup, constant=_constant), sense = p.LpConstraintGE, rhs = -CONSTANT)
model.addConstraint(other)
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for answering. I have tried all the variants, but the time needed increases like crazy, perhaps due to the complexity.
Is there any good way to reduce it? I tried converting it to a dictionary(the numpy arrays), but could not think of a good way to do it either..

Comment: have you profiled the code? Are you sure the performance problem is indeed in the adding of the constraints? 400.000 constraints is large but not impossible. How long does it take you to run that part? Finally, how long does it take to solve? if a problem that big solves quickly, maybe you can preprocess your data to only create the needed constraints.